# Elegant way to code generated coffeescript in ruby?

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, sinatra

I have the following which converts a coffeescript when ...../coffee/xxxx.js is called. For example I am trying to load variables which compliments the script to be loaded. should I load it in a separate js file or any elegant way of injecting it as coffee script as well?

```
get "/coffee/*.js" do
    filename = params[:splat].first
    coffee "../public/coffee/#{filename}".to_sym
end
```

Comment: are you asking how to combine scripts in different files, or how to make sure scripts with dependencies or ordered correctly?

Comment: hmm. I was thinking of how to load, for example... var abc = "123" into the coffeescript response above. hope this makes sense. ordered correctly is a requirement as well :)